# MySQL 8 Trick to Grant Permission on User from Several Distinct IP

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have 20+ static IPs that I want the same user to have grant access to. I am on Aurora-MySQL 8 and I wonder if there is a way to give permission to this user without specifying each IP.

For example, I have these lines:

```
grant select on *.* to debezium@<first_ip>;
grant select on *.* to debezium@<second_ip>;
```

The IPs are AWS-specific IPs and I don't see a pattern in them. Is there some tricks that I can use so that I can avoid writing 20 grant SQLs because there are 20 distinct IPs?

Comment: Do these IP addresses have the corresponding host names?

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't. I can double-check again, but if it has a hostname, that would make it easy to create the corresponding grant SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the wildcards normally used in `LIKE` predicates, i.e. `%` and `_`. But these wildcards are pretty limited. For example, they're not as flexible as regular expressions.

But if the IP addresses are so distinct that there is no pattern, then there's no practical way you can do use those wildcards to specify a fixed set of 20 IP addresses in one `GRANT` statement.

You could do this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `debezium@'%';
```

This would allow clients from *any* remote IP address to connect. That is, any remote IP address that is allowed through the AWS firewall.

Maybe that's the best option for you. [Define an AWS Security Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html) with rules to allow your list of specific IP addresses.

Comment: Thank you. Also, would you know if there is a limit to the number of MySQL users that can be created and whether there is a performance hit if a certain number of MySQL users are created? I doubt it but got curious about this.

Comment: In theory, you might create enough MySQL users that the size of the system tables would become a problem, but it would have to be in the millions. I've worked on servers that had over 1500 MySQL users per instance, and we never noticed. Any performance challenges from querying our application's data far outweighed the authentication. Keep in mind that MySQL caches the contents of the system tables (hence needing to run FLUSH PRIVILEGES if you INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE the system tables).